# Angular Component Interaction focus and blur output events

Tags: angular, events, components

I was wondering what the best approach is for when you have a parent and child component and the child component contains an input with focus/blur events that the parent would like to be aware of.

I want the parent to also provide any data that it could then use when said output returns value back.

For example, if I had a running total on parent and wanted child focus/blur events to effect this total I would do the following:

Parent component template:

```html
<div>Total: {{ total }}</div>
<app-child (focusEvent)="total = total + $event" [outputVals]="{focus: 10, blur: -3}"></app-child>
<app-child (focusEvent)="total = total + $event" [outputVals]="{focus: 2, blur: -1}"></app-child>
```

Child component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: 
  `<div>
    <label for="input1">Focus adds {{ focusVal }}. Blur adds {{ blurVal }}</label>
    <input type="text" id="input1" (focus)="focusEvent.emit(focusVal)" (blur)="focusEvent.emit(blurVal)" />
  </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() focusEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input() outputVals: {focus: any, blur: any};
  
  focusVal: any;
  blurVal: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.focusVal = this.outputVals.focus;
    this.blurVal = this.outputVals.blur;
  }

}
```

Here is the above example in a working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u1vy6f

So my question here is, is this the correct approach or is there a better way?

Comment: I've read a good articles that might be help you : https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/four-ways-of-listening-to-dom-events-in-angular-part-1-event-binding-3ec7e9f51a1d

https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/four-ways-of-listening-to-dom-events-in-angular-part-2-hostlistener-1b66d45b3e3d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine. Using child component with `@Output`/`@Input` early on is good practice and makes everything very reusable.

#### There are a few changes I would suggest:

I would advise against doing operations in your template. It makes it harder to find, change and debug. Instead, I would make any calculation in the child/parent component.

I also recommend using banana in a box `[()]` when possible. It makes it clear that the goal is a two way binding.

In your case, you want to bind the `total`, removing the `(focusEvent)="total = total + $event"` and replacing it with a two way binding seems more logical:

```
<app-child [(total)]="total"></app-child>
```

Note that banana in a box has some disadvantages in some cases ([refer to the last section of this article](https://medium.com/@preethi.s/angular-custom-two-way-data-binding-3e618309d6c7)), in which case you can just bind the parent `total` to a child `@Input`, and have a child's `@Output` call a parent function separately.
Something like:

```
<app-child [total]="total" (totalChange)="parentFunction()"></app-child>
```

Apart from that you could maybe separate your `[outputVals]` into two `@Input` variables `focusVal` and `blurVal` respectively, to make it easier to edit the template on a whim (typing a whole object is hard :D). Although this is more of a design choice, the way you do it is perfectly fine as well.

I forked your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trsf2w) to show possible modifications I mentioned.